# How to make site-to-site vpn with AWS/nginx/Zend

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, zend-framework, vpn

We have a Zend (1.12.20) php webapp that runs on AWS via docker containers.  We also have nginx routing requests between this php webapp and other webapps.

The php webapp has a public front-end and an administrative back-end.  i.e.

```
http://public-url.com
http://public-url.com/administrative-backend
```

We want to limit access to `http://public-url.com/administrative-backend` to only users that are on a site-to-site vpn while keeping the public frontend accessible to all of the internet.

Which layer of the stack should this be implemented in?  Is AWS capable of distinguishing requests to a particular URL served by a container and making some of them require VPN authorization?  Can nginx handle this somehow?

**How can I limit access to a specific portion of a php webapp to vpn users while leaving the rest of the webapp publicly accessible?**

Comment: Couldn't you just check the ip address and deny access based on that? If you are vpn'ing into the same lan that the backend is on, then surely any ips touching it should be coming from that lan and likely a 10.x.x.x address. If the backend isn't on the lan, requiring access from a public static ip address assigned to the network you vpn into should be fine.

Comment: "check the ip address and deny access" at which layer?  The entire php application (front-end and administrative screens) are running in the same docker container.  I don't think I can/want to block access to the docker-container (or the EC2 it's on) as a whole b/c that would prevent access to the public facing front-end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nginx to allow access to / to the public, but allow access to /administrative backend only from authorized IPs/networks like so:

```
location ~ /administrative-backend {
  allow   172.31.0.0/16;
  deny    all;
}
```

172.31.0.0/16 could be your VPC or VPN's IP address. Please check http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location for more details.

If you're looking for something built into AWS, it has tools to route traffic depending on the request path (in this case /* vs /administrative-backend/*). Check out application load balancers (not the classic ELB) https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/.

What I would do though, fore more security, is put the public and private (admin) in separate containers. Just disable all the admin stuff in the container that would serve the public.

Comment: How would you use an application load balancer's Listener rules to prevent requests from going to `/administrative-backed` unless they were on the vpn?  When configuring the rules, I only see options to forward the request to different target groups based on the request path or the request host, not where the request originated.